# Magento oauth with android

Tags: java, android, oauth, magento-1.9, scribe

I am using scribe library to register android with Magento.

But I am getting error:

```
org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<p>The requested URL /oauth/initiate was not found on this server.</p>
```

But my key,secret and url all are correct. I defined user and roles correctly.

I took reference from here:https:[//gmartinezgil.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/using-the-magento-rest-api-in-java-with-scribe/](https://gmartinezgil.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/using-the-magento-rest-api-in-java-with-scribe/)

My code is like this:
calling Asyntask from activity: `new OauthAsyncTask().execute();`

and then my task is:

```
public class OauthAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                // oauth for magento api access
                OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                        .provider(MagentoThreeLeggedOAuth.class)
                        .apiKey(MAGENTO_API_KEY)
                        .apiSecret(MAGENTO_API_SECRET)
                        .build();

                Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

                String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);

                Verifier verifier = new Verifier("Getting TOken");

                Log.e("authorizationUrl:", authorizationUrl);


                Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

                Log.e("accessToken:", accessToken.toString());


                OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, "MAGENTO_REST_API_URL"+ "/products");
                service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
                Response response = request.send();

                Log.e("response:", response.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
    }
```

// auth class

```
public static final class MagentoThreeLeggedOAuth extends DefaultApi10a {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://myapp.com/";

    @Override
    public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
        return BASE_URL + "oauth/initiate";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
        return BASE_URL + "oauth/token";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token token) {
        return null;
    }


    }
```

Please help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is silly but tricky, I asked my Magento developer that what is the **BASE URL** he replied with "http://myapp.com/" and got stuck with above problem, when I searched about it more, I found that some users using **BASE URL** like "http://myapp.com/magento" or "http://myapp.com/magento/index.php" etc. So I found that the real path was "http://myapp.com/index.php", it was not directed to **BASE URL**. So some times when product is in development mode these kind of problems occur and just confirm with magento dev's what is exact path.